# Can ServiceStack's TypeSerializer be made to handle boxed objects?

Tags: serialization, servicestack

Is there any way for ServiceStack's `TypeSerializer` to handle boxed objects with a bit more success?  I'm imagining an extension/setting for it to encode types as necessary. For example if I were to serialize and deserialize:

```cs
Object x = Guid.NewGuid()
Object y = serializer.DeserializeFromString(serializer.SerializeToString(x))
```

I would end up with a boxed string in my new `Object` `y`, rather than a boxed `Guid`. It would be nice if it would know enough to give me a boxed Guid. Is it this possible?  Has such a feature been considered for `TypeSerializer`?

Comment: What role does the TypeSerializer have in the above API? i.e. What's the full code example you wish to achieve in the JSV TypeSerializer? and why.

Comment: I have edited in a fuller code sample to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type information emitted on the wire for value types. You either need to specify the type information on the call site, e.g:

```
object y = x.ToJsv().FromJsv<Guid>();
```

Or the type information is on the type you're deserializing into, e.g:

```
public class Poco { 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

var dto = new Poco { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }.ToJsv().FromJsv<Poco>();
```

Or you can use the dynamic API, e.g:

```
object id = JsonObject.Parse(new Poco { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }.ToJson())
    .Get<Guid>("Id");
```